# Find and replace with same wildcard

Tags: sed, replace

I want search with a wildcard and replace with same wildcard. For example search for specific fruits name and replace it with same names at different positions.

Input:

```
fruit_id "Apple"; salad_id ""; 
fruit_id "Mango"; salad_id "";
fruit_id "Kiwi"; salad_id "";
```

Expected output:

```
fruit_id "Apple"; salad_id "Apple"; 
fruit_id "Mango"; salad_id "Mango";
fruit_id "Kiwi"; salad_id "Kiwi";
```

I am using sed and for obvious reason it dosn't work:

```
sed 's/fruit_id "..*"; salad_id "";/fruit_id "..*"; salad_id "..*";/g'
```

Comment: `awk '$4=$2' FS='"' OFS='"' file`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may capture the parts and use placeholders in the replacement that refer to the values captured:

```
sed 's/\(fruit_id "\([^"]*\)"; salad_id \)"";/\1"\2";/g' file > newfile
```

**Details**:

- `\(fruit_id "\([^"]*\)"; salad_id \)` - Group 1 (`\1`):

  - `fruit_id "` - `fruit_id "` substring
  - `\([^"]*\)` - Group 2 (`\2`): any 0+ chars other than `"`
  - `"; salad_id`  - a `"; salad_id`  substring
- `"";` - a `"";` substring.

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/Z41OXx):

```
s='fruit_id "Apple"; salad_id ""; 
fruit_id "Mango"; salad_id "";
fruit_id "Kiwi"; salad_id "";'

sed 's/\(fruit_id "\([^"]*\)"; salad_id \)"";/\1"\2";/g' <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```
fruit_id "Apple"; salad_id "Apple"; 
fruit_id "Mango"; salad_id "Mango";
fruit_id "Kiwi"; salad_id "Kiwi";
```

Comment: I don't think that using 2 capture groups is useful nor efficient. One is enough, see my answer.

Comment: @CCH Your `sed 's/fruit_id "([^"]*)"; salad_id "";/fruit_id "\1"; salad_id "\1";/g'` answer is wrong, and using two groups makes the regex shorter keeping performance at almost the same level.

Comment: Thanks I fixed my answer. I still think that using only one group is more readable for somebody new to capturing groups.

Comment: @CCH That is your opinion. It has nothing to do with the solution correctness.

Comment: I never said it's wrong, only that it's confusing for beginners.

Comment: @CCH Sorry, I must have understood your comment wrong.

Comment: can you explain this "\([^"]*\)", does it work if there is only one letter word like "A" in place of "Apply"?

Comment: @kashiff007 It works well as `"([^"]*)"` matches `"`, then captures *0 or more * chars other than `"` into Group 1 and then matches a `"`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
sed 's/fruit_id "\([^"]*\)"; salad_id "";/fruit_id "\1"; salad_id "\1";/g'
```

The idea is to use a capture group using parenthesis, and then to re-use the captured text using `\1`

See this tool for a detailed explanation of your example :
https://regex101.com/r/N4sfGA/1

Comment: Your sed command [fails to work](https://ideone.com/99wuQh). Regex101 does not support POSIX BRE syntax, you should be careful using the patterns tested there in `sed`.

Comment: You're right, thanks, I fixed the escaping of the parenthesis.

Comment: Still, there is no point using such a verbose replacement pattern, you can make it much shorter with two backreferences. See [**my answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57608615/3832970). Capturing groups are meant exactly for that: re-insert match parts we need to keep in the resulting string.

Answer (score 1):

An `awk` solution

```
awk '{$4=$2}1' FS='"' OFS='"' file
fruit_id "Apple"; salad_id "Apple";
fruit_id "Mango"; salad_id "Mango";
fruit_id "Kiwi"; salad_id "Kiwi";
```

Split the data by `"` then copy data from second field to fourth field.